# Where do I need to put file composer.json for composer to work with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have installed composer from [this link](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), but I still could not find where do I need to place the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the root of your project. Because you mentioned symfony, just have a look at the `composer.json` from the symfony-standard edition

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/

Or even better: Follow t[he official instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) and use symfony-standard as starting point for your project directly.

> Start by visiting the Symfony2 download page at http://symfony.com/download. On this page, you'll see the Symfony Standard Edition, which is the main Symfony2 distribution.

You can [forkt it directly from github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/).

Answer (score 1):

I just found on other topic that you can use :

```
php composer.phar --working-dir=/home/user/folder/ update
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a file called 'composer.json' 
See this document "https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#declaring-dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a composer.json file by using the composer init command whilst in the directory you want it to be created in

```
composer init
```

or

path/to/composer.phar init

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.